# How hard should water based polyurethane get?

Tags: woodworking, wooden-furniture, polyurethane

I made a farmhouse table and stained it with Rust-oleum water based stain and then use the Varathane Triple Thick Polyurethane on top. I have let the table sit out in the garage for a week to cure, but I case still scratch it with my finger nail, like hard wax. Is this normal or will it cure harder? Is this a bad Polyurethane to use?

Comment: By definition that isn't a "typical" poly... I know nothing about how long it takes to fully cure but would suggest contacting the manufacturer to ask. Typically a thick coat _does_ take longer than a thin coat, sometimes longer than several thin coats.

Comment: What has the temperature been like in your garage?  The manufacturer lists the application temperature range as 55°-90°, and generally the cure time goes up pretty fast the lower you get in that range.  If it's dry to the touch and stopped off-gassing, I'd bring it into a conditioned space to cure.

Comment: The weather has been about low 40° high 60° since I applied it, and my garage is unheated and uninsulated. I can try bringing it in to cure more. I am wondering if this is normal for any poly and if I should try switching to a different poly. Maybe the triple thick blend is not a good one.

Comment: I accepted an answer. However, I do have to say that in my opinion the tripple thick poly is a inferior product. I used the regular poly also and compared the results. The tripple thick seems more waxy and leaves some brush strokes.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming 70°F, 7 days to cure. You stated your temp has been 40°-60° and did not state humidity. There is nothing wrong with the product, you have used it outside of parameters recommended by the manufacturer (see text below). Take it into a temperature and humidity controlled space and hopefully it will cure hard.

> Dry times are based on 70°F and 50% relative humidity.
>   Dry times may be affected by temperature, humidity and
>   ventilation. Allow more time at cooler temperatures. Triple
>   Thick Polyurethane will be dry to touch in approximately 2
>   hours and can be recoated in 2 hours. Allow 48 hours cure
>   before light use of the project. Allow 7 days for full cure.